# permute arguments of matrix with regex

Tags: python, regex, perl, sed

To increase the performance in a FORTRAN code, I'd like to permute the indices of arrays such that the 4th index is moved to the second place, for example, I want to change the following line

```
ts(l,i,j,k) = ts(l,i,j,k1(i,j))
```

to

```
ts(l,k,i,j) = ts(l,k1(i,j),i,j)
```

Note that this is only an example line, the indices are not always called i,j,k,l... i just know the name and the rank of the array. So I cannot just separate the 4 arguments at the commas, since one single argument can also be a matrix having a comma (in the above case k1(i,j)). So my first idea

```
sed -r  's/ts\(([^,]+),([^,]+),([^)]+),([^,]+)\)/ts\(\1,\4,\2,\3\)/g' *.F
```

fails in this case (rhs in the above line of code), as it gives:

```
ts(l,k,i,j) = ts(l,j),i,j,k1(i)
```

What I need is a regex that splits my indices of the array only when at maximum 1 bracket is opened. Can someone give me a hint how to do this with sed/python/perl?

best wishes

Comment: Are you sure that parentheses will never be nested deeper than that?

Comment: Are you sure this will improve your performance?  I would expect a decrease in performance from this provided that your loops are written in the proper order.  (Of course, it doesn't hurt to experiment and see provided that you have the old version checked into your VCS)

Comment: And these days, `fortran` is not spelled in all caps :)

Comment: @Tim yes I think it will not go deeper... if there are 1-2 exceptions, I will be happy to fix those lines by hand.

Comment: @mgilson Not I'm not sure, but I want to try it out if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if parentheses are not nested any more deeply than in your example:

```
sed -r  's/ts\(((\([^()]*\)|[^(),])*),((\([^()]*\)|[^(),])*),((\([^()]*\)|[^(),])*),((\([^()]*\)|[^(),])*)\)/ts(\1,\7,\3,\5)/g' *.F
```

Not that it's very pretty...

**Explanation:**

```
(        # Match and capture...
 (       # either
  \(     #  an opening parenthesis
  [^()]* #  any number of non-parenthesis characters
  \)     #  a closing parenthesis
 |       # or  
  [^(),] #  a character besides parentheses or comma
 )*      # any number of times
)        # End of capturing group
```

Comment: I get this:
sed: -e expression #1, char 126: Invalid preceding regular expression

Comment: Hm, I don't use `sed`, so I just copied your example from the question and only swapped the regex. Since I'm not using any different regex features than you do, I don't know what might be the problem. Perhaps I've made a mistake in pasting...

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: Ah, there was an unescaped closing parenthesis in your regex. Does it work now?

Comment: no, unfortunately its not working... could not find out whats wrong so far

Comment: Just to make sure: Your regex did work, it just produced an incorrect result, right?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Just FYI: "Its not working" is a very useless statement. Specify *exactly* what you mean.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Yes, exactly like that. So what you should have said is "Its not working, I get the same error as in my first comment".

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: Are we talking about the same regex? I was asking what happens when you run *your* regex.

Comment: @Tim If I run my regex, then I get 
ts(l,k,i,j) = ts(l,j),i,j,k1(i)
I updated this in my original post

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: I think I've got it. `sed` doesn't support non-capturing `(?:...)` groups. If I change them to normal groups and renumber the backreferences accordingly, does it work then?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a direct regexp is a bit difficult. If you have script language available, try the following. After you detected a line containing the array access.
(in python)

```
import re
def getArguments(rhs):
    """
        Separates string on commas that are in the first level parentheses
    """
    lvl = 0
    argSplits = []
    for i, c in enumerate(rhs):
        if c == '(':
            lvl += 1
            if lvl == 1:
                argSplits.append(i)
        elif c == ')':
            lvl -= 1
            if lvl == 0:
                argSplits.append(i)
                break
        if lvl < 0:
            raise ValueError('Parentheses do not match')
        if lvl == 1:
            if c == ',':
                argSplits.append(i)
    args = []
    for i in range(len(argSplits)-1):
        args.append(rhs[argSplits[i]+1:argSplits[i+1]])
    return args

line = r'ts(l,i,j,k) = ts(l,i,j,k1(i,j))'
# get righthand side of equ
rhs = re.split('=', line)[1]   
# get arguments
args = getArguments(rhs)
# args = ['l', 'i', 'j', 'k1(i,j)']

# try: line = r'ts(l,i,j,k) = ts(l,i,j,k1(i(am(crazy(!))i),j))'
# you get: getArguments(rhs) --> ['l', 'i', 'j', 'k1(i(am(crazy(!))i),j)'
```

Once you have the argument list, you can just permute them when you put the string back together